# How to extract data from json data for the below example from the API

Tags: php, html, json

```
{"Dina-Kar":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarPool":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarStore":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarOnline":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarParts":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarJack":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarTunes":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarSmart":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarWash":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarRound":{"com":"available"}}
```

I need the out put as Dina-Kar.com is available.And need to run the loop Dynamically using PHP script for all the available values.

Can you please help me like that out put.

Comment: for the below answer can you please display in the HTML format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live at [codepad](http://codepad.org/qSpto37h)

The class:

```
class DomainChecker
{
  private $domains;

  public function __construct( $domainlist )
  {
    $this->domains = json_decode( $domainlist );
  }

  public function Exists( $domain, $tld )
  {
    return 
       isset($this->domains->$domain) && 
       isset($this->domains->$domain->$tld) && 
       $this->domains->$domain->$tld != 'available';
  }

  public function ListAll()
  {
    $result = '';
    foreach($this->domains as $domainname => $domain)
      foreach($domain as $tldname => $tld)
         $result .= "$domainname.$tldname\t$tld\n";
    return $result;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
$domainchecker = new DomainChecker('{"Dina-Kar":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarPool":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarStore":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarOnline":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarParts":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarJack":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarTunes":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarSmart":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarWash":{"com":"available"},"DinaKarRound":{"com":"available"}}');

$domain = 'Pome-Tek';
$tld = 'com';

if( $domainchecker->Exists( $domain, $tld ))
  echo "$domain.$tld is not available\n\n";
else
  echo "$domain.$tld is available\n\n";

echo $domainchecker->ListAll();
```

Output:

```
Pome-Tek.com is available

Dina-Kar.com    available
DinaKarPool.com available
DinaKarStore.com    available
DinaKarOnline.com   available
DinaKarParts.com    available
DinaKarJack.com available
DinaKarTunes.com    available
DinaKarSmart.com    available
DinaKarWash.com available
DinaKarRound.com    available
```

Comment: then here it will show the result for the $domain is available or not.
Here i need to run the loop and display the result for each domain in the list generated by the API

Comment: I Need to generate the List from the $s taking the Names like Dina-kar,DinakarPool and all the values from the data, can you please help me in that way

Comment: Thans for the Help, The out had received as i needed

Comment: can it be done using json_decode for json response as i shown and the output must be the same as you did?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking, please elaborate?

Comment: when we get the response in Json format and i am converting into json _decode($string), Then the out put is in this format
stdClass Object ( [Dina-Kar] => stdClass Object ( [com] => available ) [DinaKarPool] => stdClass Object ( [com] => available ) [DinaKarStore] => stdClass Object ( [com] => available ) [DinaKarOnline] => stdClass Object ( [com] => available ) [DinaKarParts] => stdClass Object ( [com] => available ) [DinaKarJack] => stdClass Object ( [com] => available ) 
Now i need to display the same output as you generated

Comment: As you see, in the constructor I also `json_decode` the string. If you do not want to use the class (**why not?**) use the code from the `ListAll()` function

Comment: ok i will use the first one then i need to integrate it in the HTML form and i tried to integrate it.Can you please suggest me how to integrate the values in the HTML form for a particular row and columns tag

Comment: can any once please let me know how we can integrate into HTMl form using the above output